# Vim / NeoVim: Map <CR> to <Esc> and <S-CR> to <CR>

Tags: vim, terminal, lubuntu, konsole

I'd like to use enter to escape insert mode, and use Shift+Enter to insert a new line instead.

The problem is my terminal emulator (Konsole running under Lubuntu) doesn't capture Shift+Enter (nor Ctrl-Enter). Any idea how I might overcome this. Am willing to change terminal emulator if it supports 24-bit colour and can scroll smoothly in NeoVim.

Relevant .vimrc

```
map <CR>   <Esc>
map <S-CR> <CR>
```

Comment: For one, Vim refers to <CR> when mapping commands as <Enter> (at least in nvim-features-new).

I tested <S-CR> and <C-CR> in neovim in urxvt and they are not considered different from <CR>.

Comment: Ctrl-Enter I can get to work in LXTerminal like this:
imap <Enter> <Esc>
inoremap <C-Enter> <Esc>

Shift-Enter, however, does not work.